Potential privacy breach due to question rate limit from IP addresses

You can only post once every 40 minutes.

I got this response from bitcoin forum while trying to ask a question, strangely I had not asked anything in last 40 minutes, In fact, that was my first question in the forum. I assumed someone from my IP, Perhaps my office might have asked a question in the same period. As I checked the newest questions in the forum there had been only one question for 40 minutes, It was by a user who has not revealed his identity. But now I have a clue about his IP and I went through the questions from his other SO profiles. Apparently, he is from my office. I did not try further to establish this fact. However, is this not a privacy breach?

Was this other post also on Bitcoin SE, or did he post on another site on StackExchange? In other words, is this a per-site ratelimit, or a ratelimit across the entire StackExchange network?

Other post was on Bitcoin SE.

No, I mean did your coworker post to Bitcoin SE, or to another StackExchange site?

That was on bitcoin SE.

This should probably be migrated to meta.se.

@DavidPostill Agree , asked the question there - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297568/potential-privacy-breach-due-to-question-rate-limit-from-ip-addresses

I'm voting to close this question as it has been asked on meta.stackexchange.com instead.
